# .NET Core Web API without changes returns 404 for url http://localhost:8083/api/values on IIS

Tags: c#

.NET Core Web API without changes returns 404 for url http://localhost:8083/api/values on IIS

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
```

this is Startup.cs code,i only change the constructor ,was anything wrong?

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

> http://localhost:8083/api/values Getting 404.0 Not Found

what should i do?

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, do not post [an images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) - they worth a downvote.

Comment: please show your startup.cs

Comment: I forget that I changed the startup.cs with configuration

Comment: ...why did you edit to paste the actual controller code, but then paste an image of the startup code? Just include the actual code if you want people to review code.

Comment: alert me that **mostly code**,and this is my first question,i'm sorry，forgive me

Comment: Startup.cs code is upload now,i can not upload before _please add some more details._

Answer (score 0):

Solved with a web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<confenter code hereiguration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```